# Get multiple return value from buttons defined in fancy box

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancy box  (jsp) that has 3 buttons, I want to return 3 different values when a user presses each of them.  Example when button 1 is presses return 1;button 2 is pressed then 2 similarly 3.

I am new to fancy box. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Some more details:
I have a main jsp, in that radio button clicked event is coded to show the fancy box (this is a jsp with 3 buttons ). When the user clicks any button, I know how to close the fancybox, but do not know how to return something to the main jsp page when user presses any of the 3 buttons.

And yes I am new to JS,  so please excuse me.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you are new to js programming in general:))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
     <a href="#" data-val="1" class="fancybox picture">toggle fancybox</a>
     <a href="#" data-val="2" class="fancybox picture">toggle fancybox2</a>
     <a href="#" data-val="3" class="fancybox picture">toggle fancybox3</a>

$("a#inline").fancybox({
    onStart: function(){
      alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
     }
    //or onComplete: function(){alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks much. Really sorry for the delay in thanking.